# There are $n! $ word made from a world of n different letter by reversing the "maximum" number between the initial letters

Tags: combinatorics, induction, contest-math, combinatorics-on-words

> A word is initially written with n different letters. Then at each step you write
> a new word of n letters, reversing the longest initial subword that does not
> produces a word of $n$ letters already written in the previous steps. Prove that we will write $n!$ words.

It is from an Italian IMO TST for IMO of 2019.

For example let $123$ a world, it become:

1. $321$
2. $231$
3. $132$
4. $312$
5. $213$
6. $123$

I think that induction work. The base case is 2 and work, let $1,2$ the two letters:
$(1,2) $ become $(2,1)$ and we have $2!$ words.
If it is true for $n$, i want prove it is also for $n+1$
I think to make a n-tuple the is the mutual position of the number less then $n+1$. For example if $n=4$ the word 23541 has the 4-tuple $(2,3,4,1)$. I think that it can help with induction (because we have now n letter). We now must understan how change the n-tuple when we change the n+1 word reversing the letter according to the hypothesis of the problem. I have made no progress from here. I hope it can be solved by induction, but it is also possible that it cannot. I'd really appreciate a solution with induction, but I'd appreciate any solution. Thanks.

Comment: If you have n-1 elements and you put another element between or on the outside of every element you have n spots to be in.  Each next world can be thought of as the previous word with a letter added and swapped with another for every word in the world. (The previous comment I made was wrong).

Comment: Thanks, now I understand